# Как объединить два спрайта?

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть две полу прозрачной картинки
Одна это голова а вторая Тело.
Оба хранятся в png.
Я хочу создать один объект с ними.
Анимировать их деформируя картинку с помощью костей.
И в коде менять Спрайты и Основные цвета.
Например
Лысую голову.png со цветом Контура = red, Основного цвет = blue, Тень Green,
На В шапке викинга со цветом Контура = orange, Основного цвет = yellow, Тень gray.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне лучше это сделать?

Comment: чёртовы амогусы добрались и до so... и кстати, конец предложения обычно не обозначается новой строчкой

Comment: @return я просто не нашел других примеров где есть разные головные уборы и цвета.